# Recommended way to communicate the user informations (id token) to resource servers in a OpenId Connect context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect

In a context with the following services:

- API Gateway/OIDC client: connect to an external OpenId Connect Provider (to get access, refresh and id tokens) and act as proxy to forward requests to other services with the access token (Authorization code flow)
- Several resource servers, incoming requests are handled by the API Gateway and include the access token (for validation, using the keys exposed by the OIDC provider)

I am using the Spring Security 5.2 Oauth2 client/resource server libraries.

What will be the recommended secure way to make all the resource servers services aware of the user information (included in the API Token).

I am evaluating several options:

1. Include the id_token in the request sent to the services. Each
   service can then validate the token (in a filter).
2. Make the API Gateway act as a token issuer to make a new enhanced token based.
   The resources servers will have to validate the token received with
   a new key exposed by the API Gateway/Token issuer. With this
   solution a custom AuthenticationManager has to be implemented.

I think option 2 is the more secure and future proof, is there any downsides I should consider? Also there are maybe other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve your goals without issuing a second level of token or sending id tokens to APIs. A common gateway solution is as follows:

- Open Id Connect Provider (OICP) issues tokens to the client and does all the deep stuff like auditing of tokens issued + UIs for managing them
- Client sends access token to resource server via API Gateway
- API Gateway validates the access token, which can involve an introspection call to the OICP
- API Gateway can send the access token to the user info endpoint of the OICP  to get user info, then forward this to resource servers - perhaps via headers
- API Gateway can be configured to cache claims (token + user info details) for subsequent calls with the same access token
- Resource servers sometimes run in a locked down Virtual Private Cloud and don't need to revalidate the access token (if you are sure this is safe)

AWS API Gateway works like this when calling lambda functions. I actually like the pattern in terms of extensibility and it can also be used in standalone APIs.

My [write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) may give you some ideas, along with some [sample authorizer code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthorizer.java) and a class that does the [OAuth work](https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java).